# Null Pointer exception when using resize Open Cv Java

Tags: java, opencv

I was writing a program to resize an image while preserving the aspect ratio. Basically, I'm trying to get the source image into a 20x20 box with the aspect ratio preserved.

```
float ra= (float)20/image.width();
Size dsize = new Size((int)(image.height()*ra),20);
// System.out.println(image.height() + " "+image.width());
//System.out.println((int)(image.height()*ra)+" " + 20);
Imgproc.resize(image,output, dsize,ra,ra, Imgproc.INTER_LINEAR);
```

The input, image is a Mat. image.height()=10, image.width()=28.   The new size would be 7,20.
However when i run the code I get a null pointer exception at Imgproc.resize(). I am unable to find the reason.
I get the same error even if I run

```
Imgproc.resize(image,output,dsize);
```

Comment: I'm sure dsize is not null. image and output are also not null as it works if i put dsize=new Size(20,20);  This will not preserve aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

- use *either* dsize *or* a scale factor, not both.
- you probably forgot:

  output = new Mat(); // you can pass empty Mat's,  but not null

Comment: I had put  Mat output = new Mat(); It works if i put dsize= new Size(20,20). But that won't serve the purpose.

Comment: I tried Imgproc.resize(image,output,size); Same issue..

Comment: ^^ you seem to contradict yourself

Comment: Sorry, where? I meant that I got the same error with Imgproc.resize(image,output,size); I simple tried declaring dsize as Size size = new Size(20,20); It worked, but this does preserve the aspect ratio. I apologise if I wasn't clear!

Comment: Size( 20, 20*img.height/img.width );

Comment: Unfortunately, thats what i did. Gave a nul pointer exception :(

Comment: Are there restrictions on the dimensions that can be passed to resize?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was interchanging the rows and columns while strong the image into Mat. I was using BufferedImage and mixed up the height and width. It works now.. Thanks everyone!!